# PageRank Calculation in Simplist Form - From Adjancy Matrix

Tags: math, matrix, multiplication, pagerank, adjacency-matrix

I was asked to create an adjancy matrix from a table of:

```
   A   B   C
A  0   1   0
B  1   0   1
C  0   0   0
```

I got this:

```
    A      B     C
A  1/6    2/3   1/6
B  5/12   1/6   5/12
C  1/6    1/6   1/6
```

I am now being asked if I can sketch out in words, formulas or pseudocode, how I can calculate from the matrix using matrix multiplication. I have tried reading the book on information but I cannot understand it.

Can anyone please tell me how I can do this in words, without too many math related symbols or explain the symbols to me. I am currently here in the IR book:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/21link.pdf

I am panicking as I will be asked this but I am not sure at all!

Even if I had it just in words in a simple form, that would be great!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an eigenvalue calculation.

http://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/googleFinalVersionFixed.pdf

Comment: I don't know what that is, I have little knowledge of that. Pretty much know basic math. Which is why I was hoping for just words. Wonder if I can just memorize the steps without the maths.

Comment: You can't do this problem unless you know the math.  The key word here is "eigenvalue".  Read the paper.